# Debugging a release build client-side crash: what are the possible ways of geting call stack?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I have a native C++ application that works fine in the office (we do testing, of course), but clients experience numerous different crashes. I know one can windbg (it's a crossplatform app - Win, Linux and Mac, but crashes occur on all platforms, so debugging either one is useful), but manipulating the client's machine (installing and registering windbg, for example) isn't an option. I wonder if there are other ways to get the call stack. Are there any tools that can instrument the binaries to provide such an information?

P. S. I can ship .pdb files along with the binaries, I guess, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: First step is ask clients for detailed information when the application crashes i.e. scenario, inputs and stuff. Clients do crash applications, which you had assumed(that is a very big mistake) to be uncrashable.

Comment: I never assumed it's uncrashable, I simply can't reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you may configure [Dr.Watson](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538) at client machine, so that if your application crashes it'll create the so-called "minidump file", which may then be opened by the debugger with the appropriate PDB.

You may also add an unhandled exception filter to your application and produce the minidump yourself in case of an irrecoverable error.

**Edit:**

In case you want to produce the dump file upon an (unhandled) exception - don't do this inside the C++ `catch (...)` block, because it's invoked **after** the unwind took place, and the original call stack is unavailable.

In order to capture & dump the call stack you should dump it **before** the stack unwinding. Like this:

```
int HandleMyException(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExc)
{
    // dump it
    MiniDumpWrite(...);

    // Unless you decide to terminate your process, return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER, so that the execution
    // continues normally after the __except block.
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

__try
{
    // Do something...
}
__except (/* stack still not unwound */ HandleMyException(GetExceptionInformation()))
{
    // unwind already took place here, nothing to dump
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, did that, but faced a problem. Please see my comment to **Luchian Grigore**'s answer.

Comment: You have to configure your debugger to use the crash dump **and** the PDB file, the former contains all the symbols (function names and etc.). Note: the PDB file should be from the same build session of your EXE.

Comment: I understand that. The crash dump works like charm, but I don't know how to get the real stack trace since I'm calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` from `catch (...)` (or `__except()) where full stack trace is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly in debug build. In release, however, I only get call stack of 5 entries.The first is a cryptic record `054f0000()`, and the second is `dbghelp.dll!Win32LiveSystemProvider::OpenMapping()`. I've checked the project settings - pdb is generated fine. What could be the cause?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong exactly without seeing the code. Worth to note that the crash dump may not always be readable if you have an invalid memory write bug. For instance if stack memory is badly overwritten you will not see a valid call stack. Beside of this I can only guess that it may be related to some onconsistency with PDB file (such as not configured debugger path to the release PDB files or etc.). Also take into account that in release build the code may be aggressively optimized, so that you'll see much less functions in the call stack

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you can use [structured exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The windows api allows you to generate a stack trace when the program crashes. A `dmp` file will be generated. You can retrieve that file and do debugging in your debug environment. No need to ship debug binaries or `pdb` files.

For cross-platform you can use [google breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/). The tool generates traces and can send them automatically or followed by a user-generated report.

Comment: Great suggestion (I mean SEH), thanks! But there is a problem: I've tried using `MiniDumpWriteDump` in the exception handler, and learnt that the chain of function calls that caused the error is absent in the stack, and my main desire is to get a call stack.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe it's probably still there, but on a different thread. Have you tried checking the call stack of every thread?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe how do you know? Are you actually monitoring the threads or does your program have only one thread. Just because you only start one thread, doesn't mean SEH or something else can't spawn new threads.

Comment: Makes sense. I meant to say there's only one thread that can crash. I've checked all the other threads. As far as I understand, the call stack is simply not available by the time execution flow gets to the exception handler (unwound? I don't understand exceptions too well).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe have you tried this on the development machine? On the machine you're actually debugging the dump files, you need to have the pdb's in order to actually see anything. What modules does the dmp file say are loaded? Are your modules there? Do they have loaded pdb's? Would be helpful to post all call stacks for all threads here, or upload a dmp file. I can take a look at it, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've got that particular problem sorted out, and the code from **valdo**'s answer really works. But now I can't see callstack in release, could you please see my last comment on **valdo**'s answer? I would appreciate any advice.