# Windows: cannot see call stack when opening a minidump

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, crash-dumps, minidump

I'm using `MiniDumpWriteDump` with `MiniDumpNormal` parameter to dump call stack in SEH exception handler. When I open the dump in VS, I can't see the callstack. I did see it with the same code two days ago when I started experimenting with dumping. I've changed something, and I don't understand what. This is a debug build (and I even saw call stack from a release build all right). I can see call stack fine in the debugger, if I put the breakpoint at `MiniDumpWriteDump` call. I can see call stack after opening the dump in VS, if the dump wasn't written from within the exception handler.
What can be the cause of stack not showing up?

[That's what my dump-writing code looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8224264/634821)

P. S. I compile with /EHa. Also tried disabling C++ exceptions at all (that definitely worked two days ago). And, of course, .pdb files are generated fine.

P. P. S. And this is what I mean by saying "call stack is not showing up".

[image]

Comment: Do the .pdb files in the visual studio build directory match the build of the .exe that generated the minidump?

Comment: @obmarg: Of course! I simply generate exception in my code and open the dump immediately, right here, on my dev machine. And please note, that call stack is displayed all right if I call `MiniDumpWriteDump` somewhere in the code and not in the exception handler!

Comment: "You've changed something." What? System configuration? Program? Do you have previous versions archived in a VCS? Can you find a version that works?

Comment: @zvrba: I have only played with project settings, and those are not versioned. There are numerous changes to the code, but all - to the code inside `__try .. __except`. And the last answer is no, otherwise I wouldn't ask here.

Comment: You can try to open your dump with WinDbg. This is much more robust tool for dumps. At least it can give you some additonal info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some circumstances, the debugger is not able to reconstruct the whole stack.
In this case, you need to open the dump with WinDbg and reconstruct the stack manually.

Comment: There's also tools which can automate the callstack extraction (and crash diagnosis) without resorting to using WinDbg. I've written a [short summary and how-to guide on the various options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33394299/434413) in this answer. 

The DebugDiag tool from Microsoft is a good choice here.